# Notification message upon cell change

Tags: vba, messagebox

So I want a message to appear when a cell changes that notifies somebody when the cell is changed. The cells that change are referenced from cells in another workbook. Here is my code so far, but it only works when I manually change the cells. It doesn't work when I change the cell being referenced.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    Set KeyCells = Range("B2:P43")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
        Is Nothing Then

        Beep

        MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & "has changed."

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If the range KeyCells contains formulas and you want to capture when the result of the formula changes, you should use the **Calculate** event.

Answer (score 1):

Try fully qualifying the Ranges, like this:

```
Set KeyCells = Sheet1.Range("B2:P43")
```